# How do I avoid an if statement with a spread operator?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have this block of code that I am repeating myself and it feels wrong but I can't figure out how to write it better

```
      const students = localStorage.getItem("Students");
      let newStudents = [{}];
      //If we already have students in local storage we want to get those and add to them
      if (students) {
        const parseStudents = JSON.parse(students as string);
        newStudents = [
          ...parseStudents,
          {
            firstName: firstNameInput.current.value,
            familyName: familyNameInput.current.value,
            email: emailInput.current.value,
            dob: dob,
          },
        ];
        //If we don't have students just add our first student
      } else {
        newStudents = [
          {
            firstName: firstNameInput.current.value,
            familyName: familyNameInput.current.value,
            email: emailInput.current.value,
            dob: dob,
          },
        ];
      }
```

Comment: `let newStudents = [{}];` <-- Why are you doing this?

Comment: `JSON.parse(students as string);` <-- Why are you doing that?

Comment: Do you have a `type` or `interface` for those Student objects?

Comment: If `students` isn't found in local storage, set it to an empty array, then just `.push()` the new object onto `students`?  (Or onto `newStudents`?  This whole thing seems very over-engineered and lacking context.)

Comment: Why not just use `newStudents.push` to add the elements you want to add?

Comment: @Dai because I finangliing with TypeScript errors and forgot to remove it. And then forgot that I needed to check undefined when using typescript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

David had the right approach I was trying to remember

```
      const students = localStorage.getItem("Students") || "";
      const newStudents = [];
      const parseStudents = JSON.parse(students);
      newStudents.push(...parseStudents);
      newStudents.push({
        uuid: uuidv4(),
        firstName: firstNameInput.current.value,
        familyName: familyNameInput.current.value,
        email: emailInput.current.value,
        dob: dob,
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

The following should work without repetitions:

```
const students =  JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("Students") as string);
const newStudents = [
  ...(students || []),
  {
    firstName: firstNameInput.current.value,
    familyName: familyNameInput.current.value,
    email: emailInput.current.value,
    dob: dob,
  }
]
console.log(newStudents);
```

Basically, if student is undefined, we just use `[]`, so we simply start with an empty array and spread.

Answer (score 0):

First, let's create a type for a student:

```
type Student = {
  firstName: string;
  familyName: string;
  email: string;
  dob: string;
};
```

Now let's write a function that will return as the students stored in the localStorage:

```
const getStudentsFromStorage = (): Student[] => {
  try {
    const students = localStorage.getItem('Students');
    if (!students) return [];

    const parsedStudents = JSON.parse(students);

    if (!Array.isArray(parsedStudents)) return [];

    //You can also add a type guard here to check whether elements are actually Students
    return parsedStudents;
  } catch {
    return [];
  }
};
```

This function checks item existing in storage, and if the stored item is actually an array, you can also add a custom type guard to guarantee that elements of the array are `Student` completely.

The last thing left is to write a function that would add the new student to the array and it can be done as follows:

```
const pushStudent = (student: Student) => {
  return getStudentsFromStorage().concat(student);
};
```

Usage:

```
let newStudents = pushStudent({
  firstName: 'name',
  familyName: 'familyname',
  email: 'email',
  dob: 'dob',
});
```

[playground](https://tsplay.dev/WKP1Gw)